# Evaluating the limit $\lim_{n\to+\infty}(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, radicals

Evaluate the limit
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}(\sqrt[n]{n}-1)^n$$

I know the limit is 0 by looking at the graph of the function, but how can I algebraically show that that is the limit?

Comment: Showing $\sqrt[n]{n}-1 \to 0$ would be a good start (actually, you need less).

Comment: See also: [How to prove $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left( \sqrt[n]{n}-1 \right)^{n}=0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1322898)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a_n:=\left(\sqrt[n]n-1\right)^n\implies\log a_n=n\log\left(\sqrt[n]n-1\right)=-\infty\implies$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\log a_n}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Since, $\frac{\log(x)}x\le\frac1e$, we have that
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt[n]{n}-1
&\le e^{1/e}-1\\
&\lt1
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt[n]{n}-1\right)^n
&\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(e^{1/e}-1\right)^n\\[3pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$