# Proving $\sqrt[n]{n} < 2-\frac{1}{n}$ inductively

Tags: inequality, induction

[image]

I have already done the first part of the problem. For the second part they give me the following hint: Use (1) with $a =\frac{n-1}{n}$, then take $n$th roots.

I'm actually quite confused. Rewriting the expression I have that $2-\frac{1}{n}=1+\frac{n-1}{n}=1+a$. Thus $\sqrt[n]{n} < 2-\frac{1}{n} = \sqrt[n]{n} < 1+a$, so $n<(1+a)^n$. From now on I don't know how to continue with the exercise. I have made several attempts starting from the last expression but it is not clear to me

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3253934/induction-with-nth-root-of-n).

Answer (score 1):

Using I) you get

$$\left(1+\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n>1+n\frac{n-1}{n}\to \left(\frac{2n-1}{n}\right)^n>n$$
$$\frac{2n-1}{n}>n^{1/n}\to 2-\frac1n>n^{1/n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your very close. Note that

$$(1+a)^n>1+na=1+n\frac{n-1}{n}=1+n-1=n$$

Can you finish it from here?

Comment: I already see it in  answers of Barry, Michell and Arnaldo. I was confused, because I thought I should use induction again. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If $a=\frac{n-1}{n} > 0$ (since $n \ge 2$) using $1$ we have
$$
(1+\frac{n-1}{n})^n > 1+ n \frac{n-1}{n}
$$
thus
$$
(1+\frac{n-1}{n})> \sqrt[n]{n}
$$
so
$$
(2-\frac{1}{n})> \sqrt[n]{n}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$2-{1\over n}=1+{n-1\over n}\implies\left(2-{1\over n}\right)^n=\left(1+{n-1\over n}\right)^n\gt1+n\cdot{n-1\over n}=1+n-1=n$$

and

$$\left(2-{1\over n}\right)^n\gt n\implies2-{1\over n}\gt\sqrt[n]n$$

Comment: Ah, I see this is essentially the same as three other answers already posted.